# is there a package called dataset in python?

Tags: python, module, package, dataset

I'm getting error while running the below query.

```
from dataset.generate_dataset import GenerateDataset
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-6c5505f9858c> in <module>()
----> 1 from dataset.generate_dataset import GenerateDataset

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataset.generate_dataset'
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, there is a [dataset package](https://github.com/pudo/dataset) in Python. However, I'm not sure if there is a generate_dataset module in it. You can still check the [documentation](https://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) just to be sure.

You might have got it confused with the [generate_dataset](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dyngen/versions/0.4.0/topics/generate_dataset) function in R.